# Printing an array in C

Tags: c, arrays, printing

I am attempting to change and then print an array in C or at least the first character. When I declare the array it is working. When I send it to another void it prints out properly as well. However, when I attempt to change it, it returns a bogus value. This is the code I have so far..

```
int main (void) {
  char value[] = "Halleluja";

  printf("The value is: %c\n", *value);
  printValue(value);
  printf("\nSecond value is: %c", *value);

  return 0;
}

void printValue(char *test[]) {

    printf("Before changing: %c", *test);

    *test = "G";
}
```

Also, how would I be able to print the string as a %s or without having to loop through the array of characters. Like, what if I wanted to change the "Halleluja" string to "Sandals"..

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's with all the empty lines?

Comment: What are you expecting `*test = "G";` to do? What does it mean to set a character equal to a string?

Comment: And you're not printing an array, you are attempting to print and change just a single value, that just happens to be the first element in an array.

Comment: I am attempting to change the string. So for example, *test = "Santa" would change the initial string to Santa.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg And what I meant is, if I wanted to print the whole string instead of just the character.

Comment: In `C` a string is a data structure, not an atom which can be changed completely by a single assignment.

Comment: And you can't do that either, because you can't change where an array "points" (since it's not actually pointing anywhere, it's not a pointer). To update a string you should [*copy* to it](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcpy).

Comment: Lastly a note about your function naming, a function named `printValue` is expected to only print a value, not modify it. For a small program like the one show, where you can see all of the program easily, it might not matter that much, but good naming is a very good habit you should learn early in your career.

Comment: But you *can* print a string without a loop using `printf` -- why do you think you can't?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some problems:

1. This:

   ```
   void printValue(char *test[]) {
   ```

   should be

   ```
   void printValue(char *test) {
   ```

   because `value` is (after decay) a `char*`, not a `char**`.
2. This:

   ```
   *test = "G";
   ```

   should be

   ```
   *test = 'G';
   ```

   because `"G"` is a string literal, but you want the character literal `'G'`.

> what if I wanted to change the "Halleluja" string to "Sandals"

Use the built-in standard library function `strcpy` from `string.h`:

```
strcpy(value, "Sandals");
```

Comment: You were right. *test should of remained the way it was. Also, now I understand what I did wrong from string literal to character. Thanks man.

Comment: Also, how would I go from this: printf("\nSecond value is: %c", *value); to printf("\nSecond value is: %s", *value); this and print out the whole string?

Comment: `printf("\nSecond value is: %s", value);`

Comment: Kudos! Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
void printValue(char *test[])
```

to

```
void printValue(char *test)
```

`*test[]` is an array of pointers but you actually need a pointer here since you are passing just one string.

Change

```
*test = "G";
```

to

```
test = "G";
```

But having said that, your piece of code has multiple problems now though syntactically everything is fine.

If I am not mistaken you actually wish to change the contents of the `array` using a pointer. This is not possible.

When you do

```
test = "Sandals";
```

`test` is simply made to point to a chunk of memory which is dedicated to store "Sandals". Safe way to change the value of `value` is :

```
strncpy_s(array, sizeof(array), "Sandals", _TRUNCATE);
```

Above is the  same as :

```
strncpy_s(array, sizeof(array), "Sandals", sizeof(array)-1);
```

Comment: Did so and it still prints out a random char in memory. In my case lowercase f

Comment: Now it did! But that got me confused. Should't  change *test (whatever is at memory address of test) instead of the test (pointer pointing to that address?)

Comment: When it comes to strings you could use the pointer(not the value pointed to) at the left side..

Comment: @WeTheFuzz : And as pointed out in the other answer, change `printf("\nSecond value is: %c", *value);` to ` printf("\nSecond value is: %c", value);` . It seems you already did.